# R. java file is not generated. How to fix it?

Tags: java, android, xml

Using Turkish char set on android resources throws an error on the line below:

```
public static final int textViewSonSatÄ±ÅŸ=0x7f050107;
```

How to fix it?

Comment: Alta turkcesini yaz, ingilizcesini ben cevireyim anlasilmiyor. (Write it down in Turkish so that I can translate into English. It is hard to understand what your problem is).

Comment: id verirken türkçe karakter kullandım ve R.java dosyası hata verdi. Bunu nasıl düzeltebilirim?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not in English

Comment: @blackbelt : don't worry, it will be soon :)

Comment: what is the error btw?

Comment: [link](http://i.hizliresim.com/VyqAAR.png) is error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your textview id name i.e (textViewSonSatÄ±ÅŸ) to some English word (e.g - textViewSonSatAtAy) or alternatively change your xml or java file encoding from Cp1252 to UTF-8.

Follow these steps:

1- Right click on your xml/java files where you are using these turkese id's(e.g- R.java or ***.xml) --> Properties --> change text file encoding from default to other (select UTF-8)-> Apply -- > OK

2- Clean your project & build again.

I haven't tested it. Hope it works!!

Answer (score 0):

`R.java` is an auto generated file when you build an android application. It contains unique identifiers (normally 32bit numbers) for elements in each category (drawable, string, layout, color, etc.) of resources (elements under directory res) available in your android application. The main purpose of R.java file is quick accessibility of resources in the project. If any resource has deleted or added to the project, R.java file will be updated automatically, this can be done by ADT plugin in Eclipse.
**The ADT plugin in Eclipse will give you a warning if you try to modify this R.java file. Even if you modified this file, it may result into unknown output of your application.**

- What is the solution when R.java file is not created ?

  Whenever you saw no R.java file in gen directory and you are getting errors like R cannot be resolved to a variable, first you have to check any errors with ****.xml files in your project and fix all the errors with xml files, next you have to clean the entire project. Almost you will fix this problem with these 2 tasks. Even after these 2 steps, if you are not getting R.java file it may be problem with ADT plugin (I didn't faced this problem but I heard some people are saying we are not able to get R.java file after these 2 steps also).
  Sometimes you will get errors like main cannot be resolved or is not a field in code setContentView(R.layout.main); when the class R has included in your project like import android.R;. Remove this import statement from your project to avoid such errors.

Comment: Only i using turkish char set give a id textview and my R.java give error i delete xml file but keeping give error

Comment: not R.java file editting xml file where using this id

Comment: <TextView
android:id="@+id/tvSatışSon"
            />   Give only this turkis ids

Comment: and after i edit TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvSatisSon" /> but still R.java give error

Comment: i do it . Project -->clean.. --> clean all project but error still.

Comment: Bro i fixed now problem. First i write  <TextView android:id="@+id/tvSatışSon" /> xml file after saved and i changed with ide propert windows after fixed. Thank for all . İ will accept your answer :D

Comment: but right solution is @amrit pal and i will accept . Because right