# Eclipse styles.xml theme error for lower android APIs

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-styles

I'm Practically a first timer so forgive me if my question sounds too easy for you.
I made a new android project in Eclipse with lower APIs (8 and 10) but I keep getting an error in styles.xml in values and also the R.java file is not created (which is because of the style problem. as I've learned, it gets generated with project->clean after the styles problem is fixed.)
but later on I made a new project with a higher API (4.0.3) at it's all good and everything is generated the way it should.
now I did my research in the following 3 questions here:
    [Eclipse Errors: styles.xml no resource, java.io.FileNotFoundException, and also R.java not regenerating](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24924522)
    [Android .R not generating - checked all common causes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17710487)
    [R. java file is not generated. How to fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26989359)
but none mention the problem being related to lower APIs.
thanks in advance for any help you can provide.

This is the line of the error:

```
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
```

and in console I get this error:

```
[2016-06-20 19:05:11 - AndroidApp] D:\Utilities\eclipse\Workspace \AndroidApp\res\values\styles.xml:7: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.AppCompat.Light'.

[2016-06-20 19:05:11 - AndroidApp] D:\Utilities\eclipse\Workspace\AndroidApp\res\values-v11\styles.xml:7: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.AppCompat.Light'.

[2016-06-20 19:05:11 - AndroidApp] D:\Utilities\eclipse\Workspace\AndroidApp\res\values-v14\styles.xml:8: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar'.
```

Comment: What error are you getting? How do you expect us to be able to help if we don't know what your problem is?

Comment: can't understand what you're trying to do.

Comment: @Blubberguy22  sorry I forgot the code. appreciate your feeback.

Comment: @rick what I'm trying to do is to use lower APIs so that my app will be accessible to a wider range of users. but when I do the styles.xml file gives erroes.